# shifting weights and locking in place at different angles

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Hi i would like to ask if there's any ways i can shift weights and lock it in place at different angles (180 degree to 90 degree)  without using electronic devices- preferably using wood as the main material. I have tried using a slider to guide the weights and by pushing the rod that is holding the weights to lock it in place. However, it is not feasible as it is too complicated and the weights does not move smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

yes, we can shift weights and lock it in place at different angles with or without using electronic devices. we can use a screw jack mechanism to lift and place weights. we have to select screw jack as per the weight & height.

Comment: Hi thanks ! i have thought of screws or gears to shift it. However, i am told that it is too complicated and it may wear and tear easily if the wood material used is of low quality :(

Comment: instead of the screw, we can use pully and rope mechanism for lifting weights.

Comment: hi thanks but apparently , i am not allowed to use screws, gears and pulley :(  so i am still thinking of other ways to do it